# Rails ActiveStorage picks random file when no file attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, image, activerecord, rails-activestorage

Im kinda new with Rails and ActiveStorage, I've been creating a simple app where a user can create an image with a title and a description and attache a picture to it.
I used scaffold referenced to user to create the Image part, and here is the image model :

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :picture
end
```

and here is the form:

```
<%= form_with(model: image) do |form| %>
  <% if image.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% image.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_field :description %>
  </div>
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :picture %>
    <%= form.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg' %>
  </div>
  

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#image_picture').bind('change', function(){
    var size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if(size_in_megabytes > 5){
      alert("Maximum file size is 5Mo")
    }
  })

</script>
```

and the image_controller :

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_image, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /images or /images.json
  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  # GET /images/1 or /images/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /images/new
  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  # GET /images/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /images or /images.json
  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    @image.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: "Image was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /images/1 or /images/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.update(image_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: "Image was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /images/1 or /images/1.json
  def destroy
    @image.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to images_url, notice: "Image was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_image
      @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:title, :description, :user_id, :picture)
    end
end
```

When I submit the form without an image, it choose a random image from my local repo and attache it to the record, I dnt know why and how to stop it

Comment: There is nothing in the code here which explains this behavior and its not a default behavior of ActiveStorage. Do you have a github repo?

Comment: yes I do, here is the link of the repo : https://github.com/DalilaBA/photo-app

Comment: I can't see anything that would explain why this is happening. I would add a test to ImagesControllerTest and see if you can replicate the behavior.